# Flask routing not working

Tags: python, flask

It's the most basic thing to ask but `@app.route('/')` is not working on my Linux server.

Below is the code :

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from app import models
import json
import time

app = Flask(__name__)
app.url_map.strict_slashes = True


@app.route('/')
def blank():
    return 'Hello ABC!'

@app.route('/driftking')
def blank2():
    return 'Hello driftking!'

# dynamic route
@app.route("/test/<search_query>")
def search(search_query):
    return search_query

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return "POST METHOD"
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return "GET REQUEST ARE NOT ALLOWED"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
    app.run()
```

Very basic app, all's working fine on local machine but not on my linux server.

E.g. if I load http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/projectname ---- it shows Hello ABC!

If I load http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/projectname/driftking -- it redirects me to http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ( i.e my server's homepage)

If I load http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/projectname/test/search -- 404 error not found

If I load http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/projectname/login -- it redirects me to http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ( i.e my server's homepage)

`127.0.0.1 - - [24/Nov/2017 19:37:01] "POST //login HTTP/1.1" 405 -`

^^This is what I get on terminal. I don't understand why I get two leading slashes everytime.

But If do http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/projectname/*insert-any-word*/login , my post req get's executed. At the same time on local machine i dont get two leading slashes `//` to the path and thus the request get's processed.

Comment: remove the second `app.run()` call.

Comment: @ArtsiomPraneuski, removed. Still not working. `127.0.0.1 - - [24/Nov/2017 21:14:07] "POST //login HTTP/1.1" 405 -`

Comment: Are you using a reverse proxy on the server? It's probably misconfigured.

Comment: @jordanm, am using https://www.vioan.eu/blog/2016/10/10/deploy-your-flask-python-app-on-ubuntu-with-apache-gunicorn-and-systemd/ to setup whole thing. How do I check if it's correctly configured or not.

Answer (score -1):

There are a couple of things wrong but try this, you'll need a proxy to help with the rerouting.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from app import models
import json
import time

from werkzeug.contrib.fixers import ProxyFix

app = Flask(__name__)
app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app)
app.url_map.strict_slashes = False


@app.route('/')
def blank():
    return 'Hello ABC!'

@app.route('/driftking')
def blank2():
    return 'Hello driftking!'

# dynamic route
@app.route("/test/<search_query>")
def search(search_query):
    return search_query

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return "POST METHOD"
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return "GET REQUEST ARE NOT ALLOWED"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Can you help with some rerouting articles?

Comment: Actually am working on rerouting, so kinda looking for that too. And the answer which you provided, ill be trying that in few minutes and inform you. But since you mentioned thag I will need some help with rerouting, I was hoping to check that part first.

Comment: Still the same issue. Not able to reach `/login'.  `[26/Nov/2017 10:31:28] "POST //login HTTP/1.1" 405 -`